# Drawing the DLS Grid for Alberta, Canada

Tags: google-maps, convert, grids-graticules, canada, township-range-section

I have DLS grid data that I downloaded from http://www.altalis.com/products/property/ats.html (AltaLIS_ATS_V4.1_Coordinates data). But I don't know how to draw the grid on Google Maps. We have Meridian, Township, Range, Section and Quarter section. Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Ok. But can i customize the map because i have to show the  wells on the alberta area and i don't want search on the top that are showing during import the KML data and vertical menu on the left side.

Comment: Please include an example record or two of the data that you downloaded within your question body.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download the polygons (shapefile) instead of the coordinate data
   which is just an ascii list.
2. Open the shapefile using [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) as I
   [originally
   suggested](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141376/) and *Save
   As* to a kml file. Alternatively use [Google Earth
   Pro](https://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/desktop.html)
   (currently free), [Shp2kml](http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html), or
   [another online
   converter](https://www.google.com/#q=shapefile+to+kml) to do the
   conversion.
3. Upload the kml file to Google Maps.