# Finding British Columbia township grid?

Tags: data, grids-graticules, canada, township-range-section

I'm looking for a shapefile of the Dominion Land Survey township grid for British Columbia. Where might I find this data?

Comment: Related question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141376/ where I'd come across a [thread on Esri GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/16426) that was asking specifically about BC. More information at that linked question describing how it is apparently maintained province by province.

Answer (score -1):

Try this
[Data – Canada Lands Surveys](https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/canada-lands-surveys/11092)

Comment: That is a potentially good resource which came up in my quick search, but preliminary browsing around didn't see the requested data available anywhere. If you know for sure it is available there, directions on how to find it would be helpful. Otherwise this might be better as a comment than an answer (particularly given it starts with 'try').